# 特定のユーザーのみ systemctl によるサービスの状態操作を許可したい

Tags: linux, systemd

今、作成したウェブアプリケーションを、 systemd の `.service` ファイルでサービス化し、かつそのアプリケーション用のユーザーを作成し、そのユーザーにてサービス(サーバー)を実行しています。

この状態で、このアプリケーションユーザーでログインしていた際には、そこから自身のサービスの状態の更新を行えるようにしたくなりました。`sudo` がこのユーザに付与されていれば、`sudo systemctl start/stop/etc... app.service` を実行して、そのアプリのサービスの状態を更新できますが、アプリのユーザーに `sudo` はできれば付与したくありません。

## 質問

systemd のあるサービスを、特定のユーザーから実行された場合は、それが root でなくても `systemctl` での状態更新を利用可能にしたいです。これは、実現する手段はあるのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudoers.d/app-user-systemctl` の中に、以下のように記載を行い、明示的にどのコマンドが sudo 可能かを列挙するのが、ちょうどよい設定方法なのではないか、と思うにいたりました。

```
app-user ALL=(root) /bin/systemctl restart app-service, /bin/systemctl start app-service, /bin/systemctl stop app-service
```

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` を使う方法だと `systemctl` コマンドすべてを実行できてしまうので "特定サービスの操作だけ" 許可したい場合に不都合だから使いたくない…なんだろうと理解しました。

---

"systemctl user service" で検索すればやりたいことに該当しそうなページがいくつかヒットしますが、そのうちの一つとして、`/etc/systemd/` 以下ではなく、実行させたいユーザーのホームディレクトリ以下にユニットファイルを`~/.config/systemd/user/*.service` の形式で配置する方法があるようです。

**参考:**
[systemdでユーザー固有のunitを動かす](https://kernhack.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/05/05/114633)

> systemdは~/.config/systemd/userにserviceファイルを置くことで、そのユーザー用のinit時の処理を動かすことができるんですね。基本的に使い方は通常と同じで、唯一違うのは--userをパラメータとして使用すること。
>
> ```
> $ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/foobar.service 
> [Unit]
> Description=User's service file
>
> [Service]
> Type=oneshot
> ExecStart=/usr/bin/touch /tmp/test.txt
> RemainAfterExit=yes
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=default.target
> ```

> このように実行します。
>
> ```
> $ systemctl --user enable foobar
> ```

Answer (score 2):

特定のユーザに特定のコマンドを許可するのがsudoだと思いますが、sudoを使いたくない場合は、実行ユーザをチェックし、特定ユーザならユーザをrooに変更し、systemctlを実行するプログラムを作成する必要があると思います。

【ソース:q.c】

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define UID (1000)
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret;
    if(getuid() != UID) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error uid not match(%d)\n", UID);
        return ret;
    }
    printf("getuid (%d)\n", getuid());
    ret = setuid(0);
    if(ret == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "setuid error(%s)\n", strerror(errno));
        return ret;
    }
    ret = system("/usr/sbin/service ssh stop");
    return ret;
}
```

実行プログラムの所有者はrootユーザに変更し、setuid権限を付与する必要があります。

```
clang q.c #or gcc q.c
sudo chown root ./a.out
sudo chmod u+s ./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

あくまで一般論ですが、`アプリケーションユーザーでログイン` すること自体を無効化したほうが健全だと思います。

サービスを実行する専用のユーザはログインシェルを `/sbin/nologin` や `/usr/sbin/nologin` にするなどしてログインを無効化して、許可された一般ユーザが sudo を通してサービスのコントロールを行う方がより良いと思います。

また、もしも専用ユーザのシェル操作が必要な場合は、`sudo -s -u ユーザID` で切り替えます。